# For loops and Dictionaries

Tags: python

```
cities = [{'City': 'Buenos Aires',
  'Country': 'Argentina',
  'Population': 2891000,
  'Area': 4758},
 {'City': 'Toronto', 'Country': 'Canada', 'Population': 2800000, 'Area': 2731},
 {'City': 'Pyeongchang',
  'Country': 'South Korea',
  'Population': 2581000,
  'Area': 3194},
 {'City': 'Marakesh', 'Country': 'Morocco', 'Population': 928850, 'Area': 200},
 {'City': 'Albuquerque',
  'Country': 'New Mexico',
  'Population': 559277,
  'Area': 491},
 {'City': 'Los Cabos',
  'Country': 'Mexico',
  'Population': 287651,
  'Area': 3750},
 {'City': 'Greenville', 'Country': 'USA', 'Population': 84554, 'Area': 68},
 {'City': 'Archipelago Sea',
  'Country': 'Finland',
  'Population': 60000,
  'Area': 8300},
 {'City': 'Walla Walla Valley',
  'Country': 'USA',
  'Population': 32237,
  'Area': 33},
 {'City': 'Salina Island', 'Country': 'Italy', 'Population': 4000, 'Area': 27},
 {'City': 'Solta', 'Country': 'Croatia', 'Population': 1700, 'Area': 59},
 {'City': 'Iguazu Falls',
  'Country': 'Argentina',
  'Population': 0,
  'Area': 672}]
```

Now, using the cities list, we want to create a list of the names for each city. Loop through each city and append it's name ('City') to the city_names list.

-----------this is what i did (below)

```
city_indices = list(range(0,len(cities)))

for city_names in city_indices:
    print(cities[city_names]["City"])
```

Output:

Buenos Aires\n
Toronto\n
Pyeongchang\n
Marakesh\n
Albuquerque\n
Los Cabos\n
Greenville\n
Archipelago Sea\n
Walla Walla Valley\n
Salina Island\n
Solta\n
Iguazu Falls\n

desired output:

```
["Buenos Aires",
"Toronto",
"Pyeongchang",
"Marakesh",
"Albuquerque",
"Los Cabos",
"Greenville",
"Archipelago Sea",
"Walla Walla Valley",
"Salina Island",
"Solta",
"Iguazu Falls"]
```

Comment: You're not appending to a list, you're just printing.

Comment: `city_names = [c['City'] for c in cities]`

Answer (score 1):

You have to append it to the list not just print it.

You can do using list comprehension,

```
In [38]: city_names = [i['City'] for i in cities]
Out[38]: 
['Buenos Aires',
 'Toronto',
 'Pyeongchang',
 'Marakesh',
 'Albuquerque',
 'Los Cabos',
 'Greenville',
 'Archipelago Sea',
 'Walla Walla Valley',
 'Salina Island',
 'Solta',
 'Iguazu Falls']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cities = [{'City': 'Buenos Aires',
  'Country': 'Argentina',
  'Population': 2891000,
  'Area': 4758},
 {'City': 'Toronto', 'Country': 'Canada', 'Population': 2800000, 'Area': 2731},
 {'City': 'Pyeongchang',
  'Country': 'South Korea',
  'Population': 2581000,
  'Area': 3194},
 {'City': 'Marakesh', 'Country': 'Morocco', 'Population': 928850, 'Area': 200},
 {'City': 'Albuquerque',
  'Country': 'New Mexico',
  'Population': 559277,
  'Area': 491},
 {'City': 'Los Cabos',
  'Country': 'Mexico',
  'Population': 287651,
  'Area': 3750},
 {'City': 'Greenville', 'Country': 'USA', 'Population': 84554, 'Area': 68},
 {'City': 'Archipelago Sea',
  'Country': 'Finland',
  'Population': 60000,
  'Area': 8300},
 {'City': 'Walla Walla Valley',
  'Country': 'USA',
  'Population': 32237,
  'Area': 33},
 {'City': 'Salina Island', 'Country': 'Italy', 'Population': 4000, 'Area': 27},
 {'City': 'Solta', 'Country': 'Croatia', 'Population': 1700, 'Area': 59},
 {'City': 'Iguazu Falls',
  'Country': 'Argentina',
  'Population': 0,
  'Area': 672}]

l = []
for d in cities:
    l.append(d['City'])
print(l)
```

prints

```
['Buenos Aires',
 'Toronto',
 'Pyeongchang',
 'Marakesh',
 'Albuquerque',
 'Los Cabos',
 'Greenville',
 'Archipelago Sea',
 'Walla Walla Valley',
 'Salina Island',
 'Solta',
 'Iguazu Falls']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
city_indices = list(range(0,len(cities)))

result = []
for city_names in city_indices:
    result.append(cities[city_names]["City"])

print(result)
```

i think this is what you want

Comment: Yes, that was it thank you! This is my 6th day learning python. (First time programmer)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to misunderstand how printing the values in python works. What you did is create a list of indices from 0 to len(cities), while the pythonic way would be to iterate over the cities list instead:

```
for city in cities:
    print(city)

# prints
{'City': 'Buenos Aires', 'Country': 'Argentina', 'Population': 2891000, 'Area': 4758}
{'City': 'Toronto', 'Country': 'Canada', 'Population': 2800000, 'Area': 2731}
{'City': 'Pyeongchang', 'Country': 'South Korea', 'Population': 2581000, 'Area': 3194}
...
```

However, as mentioned already, since in this example we only want to create a list of city names and print it, we can use a generator like this:

```
city_names = list(city['City'] for city in cities)
print(city_names)

# prints
['Buenos Aires', 'Toronto', 'Pyeongchang', 'Marakesh', 'Albuquerque', 'Los Cabos', 'Greenville', 'Archipelago Sea', 'Walla Walla Valley', 'Salina Island', 'Solta', 'Iguazu Falls']
```

In the given example, you split the desired output with newlines. Altough that doesn't look like an easily replicable format, you can use the json module to pretty-print JSON objects (so convert a python list to a JSON array and print it) like so:

```
import json

city_names = list(city['City'] for city in cities)
formatted_output = json.dumps(city_names, indent=4)
print(formatted_output)

# prints
[
    "Buenos Aires",
    "Toronto",
    "Pyeongchang",
    "Marakesh",
    "Albuquerque",
    "Los Cabos",
    "Greenville",
    "Archipelago Sea",
    "Walla Walla Valley",
    "Salina Island",
    "Solta",
    "Iguazu Falls"
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the deep explanation it was very helpful! I just got confused since I didn't knew how to use the append method in a for loop.